# Why isn't my initial sendEther function not recognized as a receive ether function, am getting the error shown below

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

Error: **This contract has a payable fallback function, but no receive ether function. Consider adding a receive ether function.**

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.5.16;

contract MyContract {

 string public functionCalled;

 function sendEther () external payable {
     functionCalled = 'sendEther';
 }
 fallback () external payable {
     functionCalled = 'fallback';
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, `receive` has been added to the standard starting from solc 0.6.0 or so. The syntax for it is exactly the same as the syntax for `fallback`, except for stating `receive` instead.

Comment: And your `sendEther` function is not recognized as `receive` because... well, it obviously has a different name.

Comment: 'rserError: Expected identifier but got '('
receive () external payable{'    I am getting this error with the receive() function, why is that?

Comment: Am I supposed to guess how you have implemented `receive` in your contract?????

Comment: you made goodvibration angry.. ask than in a new question please with more details about version and the problem

Comment: Majd TL no need. This was a practice exercise, learning different ways of sending ether to a smart contract not practical implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallback function was used in two ways: to receive ether payments and as a function dispatcher.

To enhance readability and improve security it was split in two function.

If you only want to accept payments just implement receive. From [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/contracts.html#receive-ether-function)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

// This contract keeps all Ether sent to it with no way
// to get it back.
contract Sink {
    event Received(address, uint);
    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

For backward compatibility it is possible to declare fallback as payable. The compiler shows a warning but it should work as usual. Just be aware that in the future it may be deprecated.